# Java - synchronization doesn't help mutual exclution

Tags: java, synchronization

I have a program in which the `Main` class would create few resources of `Node` class which contains a runnable thread that executes while the resource of the `Node` class has been created. i have a shared resource `Receive` class that the `Node` class uses. but when couple of `Node` resources reach the synchronized method `rcv()` from the Resource class the program doesn't give any regard to the  mutual exclusion and the output is amalgam from different parts of the different `Node` classes

```
public class Main 
{
  //field

  //methods
    public static void main(String[] main)
    {

        Node node1 = new Node(1);
        Node node2 = new Node(2);

    }//main
}
```

Node class

```
public class Node 
{
    private int index;
    public Node(int index)
    {
         this.index = index;
         receive();
    }
    public void receive()
    {
        (new Thread() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Receive r = new Receive();
                r.rcv(index);
            }//run method
        }).start();
    }//send method
}
```

Receive class

```
public class Receive
{
    synchronized public void rcv(int index)
    {
        System.out.print(index+":");
        System.out.print(index);
    }
}
```

the output should be `1:1 2:2` or `2:2 1:1` but never something like `1:2:21`

Comment: What is releation between ReceiveResource  and Receive?

Comment: `synchronized` for non static method synchronizes on the instance. In your case you produce two unrelated instances, so both synchronizations are independent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each of your threads creates its own `ReceiveResource` object (I guess with class `Receive` you really mean `ReceiveResource`?) and calls `rcv()` on their own object.

The threads will not be mutually synchronized because they are calling `rcv()` on different instances of `ReceiveResource`. You need them both to use the same `ReceiveResource` object if you want the calls to be mutually exclusive.

Answer (score 3):

You are locking on object-level, and create two different `Receive`-objects. The two `Receive` objects will not be synchronized with each other, only with itself. If you want to synchronize both `Receive` objects with each other, they have to lock on the same object. In the code below I created an object `_lockObject`. This variable is static, which means it's shared over all the `Receive`-objects.

Try this code:

```
public class Receive
{
    private static Object _lockObject = new Object();

    public void rcv(int index)
    {
        synchronized(_lockObject)
        {
            System.out.print(index+":");
            System.out.print(index);
        }
    }
}
```

PS:

This code:

```
public synchronized void rcv()
{
     ...
}
```

is equivalent to:

```
public void rcv()
{
    synchronized(this)
    {
        ....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As others have mentioned in his comments and Jesper has mentioned in his answer, you should use a single ReceiveResponse object, shared by both the threads/nodes.

But did you know there is already an class called `java.util.concurrent.Exchanger` which achieves the similar thing? If you want the functionality, you can use it. If you want to practice and learn synchronization, then yes, fix your code according to the comments/answer.

Also, you shouldn't create a new thread (starting a thread) from inside a constructor. You are leaking the 'this' in that case. You can refer Java Concurrency In Practice book to understand what this means and how to handle these situations.